# How to display text in a new activity when two radio buttons from two different activities are clicked?

Tags: java, android-studio, radio-button

I am using Java and Android Studio. I have one activity with a few options to select from, and once one of them is selected, they click the button that takes them to the next activity. They do the same thing again except this time when the user clicks the button it takes them to a new activity where it displays the results based on the two radio buttons clicked previously. How can I do this?

Comment: The question is how do I fix the view error marked in red?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send some variable through intent and onCreate() method of the second activity, you can use that variable to differentiate your functionality.
This video demonstrates the functionality of the radio button: https://youtu.be/zJG9Prn3vZ0
In this video you can know how to pass arguments to another activity: https://youtu.be/OMCctaE66b8
Hope that helps you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare a method inside another method. Put a closing brace after onCreate.

When you are opening a new activity, you are doing it with an Intent. Put the values you want to send (bool clicked) the new activity inside the intent

Comment: I think you cannot put more values inside one case. Write 2 cases one after another without a break

Comment: I am not sure how you want to reuse the IDs, but if you want to store the value of the radio button, store it in a private field of the activity.